# QuickSort (Java) implementation either overflows or stops short

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I have been reading through all of the QuickSort questions on SO, but I cannot resolve this specific problem. By referencing the other questions and comparing my faults to theirs I have gotten to a specific point, that I cannot find the answer to, even in Debug mode.

<s>I was repeatedly getting out of bounds -1, so I added a conditional check for</s>

```
if(pivot > 0)
```

and that stopped the overflow, but since I am using 0 as my partition, It partitions once and then terminates. The first partition is correct, but if I change that number to include 0, the I get infinite recursion again. If I completely take the line out, I get index out of bounds errors that I cannot seem to tackle.

Here's where I am so far:

```
public class QuickSort {

int[] array;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    QuickSort qs = new QuickSort();
    qs.array = new int[] {35, 82, 2, 24, 57, 17};

    qs.quickSort(qs.array, 0, qs.array.length - 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < qs.array.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(qs.array[i]);

    }

}

public void quickSort(int[] array, int left, int right) {

    if(array.length == 1) {

        return;

    }

    if(left < right) {

        int pivot = partition(array, left, right);

        quickSort(array, left, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, right);

    }

}

public int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {

    if(array.length == 1) {

        return right;

    }

    int pivot = array[0];
    int pivotIndex = 0;
    int leftPointer = left - 1;
    int rightPointer = right + 1;

    while(pivotIndex < right) {

        if(leftPointer > rightPointer) {

            break;

        }

        leftPointer++;

        while(leftPointer < array.length - 1 && array[leftPointer] <= pivot) {

            leftPointer++;

        }

        rightPointer--;

        while(rightPointer > leftPointer && array[rightPointer] > pivot) {

            rightPointer--;

        }

        if(leftPointer < rightPointer) {

            int temp = array[leftPointer];
            array[leftPointer] = array[rightPointer];
            array[rightPointer] = temp;

        } else {

            int temp = array[rightPointer];
            array[rightPointer] = array[pivotIndex];
            array[pivotIndex] = temp;

        }

    }

    return rightPointer;

}
```

EDIT: After a few more alterations, I can now get it to always return an array without overflow, but it still only partitions once.

Comment: Your `partition` method seems to be starting from index 0. Shouldn't it start at `left`?

Comment: @krillgar my understanding is that it will go through all the calls of the first recursive call, then come back and do all the calls through the second recursive call

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wasn't thinking at all. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I fixed it now. You were increasing the left and right pointers within the partition method before you wanted to (outside of the "checks"). Change your partition method as follows:

```
public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {

  if(array.length == 1)
      return right;

  int pivot = array[0];
  int pivotIndex = 0;
  int leftPointer = left; // Remove the +1
  int rightPointer = right; // Remove the +1

  while(pivotIndex < right) {
      if(leftPointer > rightPointer) {
          break;
      }
    //leftPointer++;

      while((leftPointer < array.length - 1) && (array[leftPointer] <= pivot)) {
          leftPointer++;
      }
      //rightPointer--;

      while((rightPointer > leftPointer) && (array[rightPointer] > pivot)) {
          rightPointer--;
      }

      if(leftPointer < rightPointer) {
          int temp = array[leftPointer];
          array[leftPointer] = array[rightPointer];
          array[rightPointer] = temp;
      }
      else {
          int temp = array[rightPointer];
          array[rightPointer] = array[pivotIndex];
          array[pivotIndex] = temp;
      }
  }
  return rightPointer;
```

}

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you so much! One more question MikeM, is there a simple way to get it to swap duplicates? Right now it just hangs.

Comment: Ah sorry, only just saw this so I'm not sure it's still relevant... but I think you could add a simple if statement that checks if they're duplicates. If they are, 'continue', otherwise carry on as normal, assuming I understand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
 if(leftPointer > rightPointer) {
        break;
    }
```

to

```
 if(leftPointer >= rightPointer) {
        break;
    }
```

inside the while loop.

Also, I think you should compare leftPointer with rightPointer after either is changed,

```
    // move to @@@@ to perform compare after possible change
    // if(leftPointer > rightPointer)      break;


    //leftPointer++; 

    while(leftPointer < array.length - 1 && array[leftPointer] <= pivot) leftPointer++;


    //rightPointer--;  

    while(rightPointer > leftPointer && array[rightPointer] > pivot)   rightPointer--;


   //@@@@
   if(leftPointer > rightPointer) break;
```

Comment: I tried to do that, and it still continues to break. I have updated my code to the above and it always returns me an array without breaking now, but it still will only partition once.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning "0" from partition whenever the array length is not 1, and setting that to the pivot. The `if(pivot >= 0)` will always be hit in that case, or it will iterate once if you used `if(pivot > 0)`, which I think is the problem. If that's right, then correcting your return from partition (to "left" ?) should fix the problem.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it didn't work. It goes infinite. If I change it to rightPointer, I do get an array that is partitioned correctly once, but it doesn't recurse until its all sorted.